# Get Ajax URL from PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I know this has been asked before, but I can't get it working.

I'm loading a file on a page whose path and name are a variable contained in a PHP script.

My script.php is outputing a variable $filename which contains the path to a file that has to be open in an ajax request.

So, the file can be for example:

'../path/to/file/filea.json' or
'../another/path/fileb.json'

I tried this in my jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'script.php',
    success:$.ajax({    
        url: ??? // This ($filename) is what I'm trying to get from the 1st Ajax call
        sucess: function(data){
                    //other code here
                    }
            })
);
```

I know $filename is wrong in the second Ajax call but how do I get the value of that variable?

Comment: In which file do you have this code? in `script.php ` ?

Comment: No, this is in a jquery script

Comment: Your code is javascript. So how can you have a php variable ? A piece is missing in your question.

Comment: give complete problem descriptions

Comment: Can you post some code from the php file? what does it echo?

Comment: @Sergio: thanks for not giving up... it isn't echoeing anythin, it just defines $filename, I guess that is the reason it isn't working. I'm now trying echo($filename) in script.php and url:data in Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem:

```
$.ajax({
    async:false,
    url: 'script.php',
    success: function(data){ 
        $.ajax({
        url: data,
            success: //code here
        })
})
```

@Sergio: script.php wasn't echoeing the output of $filename... Thanks for reminding!

Comment: Podes aceitar esta resposta :)

Comment: Don't use async:false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

inside script.php

```
echo json_encode($filename); //somewhere you need to have this echo.
```

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data); //or console.log() and doublecheck you have the right info
        $.ajax({
            url: JSON.parse(data),
            success : function (data) {
                //other code here
            }
        })
    }
}); // added a extra } to close the ajax
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            url: "script.php",
            success: function(data){
                $.ajax({
                    var someParam=data; //response Data from 1st Ajax Call
                    type: "post",
                    url: "example.php",
                    data: 'page='+someParam,
                    success: function(data){

                    //Do More Here!

       });
});
```

Comment: the "example.php" URL in the 2nd Ajax is what I'm trying to get from the 1st Ajax